Why does "dfx deploy" work, but "dfx deploy playground" gives an error?
I've created an auction platform on ICP, which deploys fine when I use dfx deploy Command. However, when I try deploying in playground mode using dfx deploy --playground, it doesn't work and I get the error message below. Can you help me understand what's going wrong?
This is the output when I do dfx deploy:
installed.
Deployed canisters.
URLs:
Frontend canister via browser
frontend:
\- http://127.0.0.1:4943/?canisterId=bd3sg-teaaa-aaaaa-qaaba-cai
\- http://bd3sg-teaaa-aaaaa-qaaba-cai.localhost:4943/
internet_identity:
\- http://127.0.0.1:4943/?canisterId=be2us-64aaa-aaaaa-qaabq-cai
\- http://be2us-64aaa-aaaaa-qaabq-cai.localhost:4943/
Backend canister via Candid interface:
backend: http://127.0.0.1:4943/?canisterId=br5f7-7uaaa-aaaaa-qaaca-cai&id=bkyz2-fmaaa-aaaaa-qaaaq-cai
internet_identity: http://127.0.0.1:4943/?canisterId=br5f7-7uaaa-aaaaa-qaaca-cai&id=be2us-64aaa-aaaaa-qaabq-cai

This is the output when I do dfx deploy --playground:
Stderr:
failed to load config from /home/samuel/project/auction/vite.config.ts
error during build:
Error: Unable to find canisters. Running `dfx deploy` should fix this problem.
at file:///home/samuel/project/auction/vite.config.ts.timestamp-1717768009422.mjs:16:9
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/modul[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/VLEJT9th.png)e_job:195:25)
at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)
at async loadConfigFromBundledFile (file:///home/samuel/project/auction/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-372dab03.js:63143:21)
at async loadConfigFromFile (file:///home/samuel/project/auction/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-372dab03.js:63028:28)
at async resolveConfig (file:///home/samuel/project/auction/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-372dab03.js:62651:28)
at async doBuild (file:///home/samuel/project/auction/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-372dab03.js:45631:20)
at async build (file:///home/samuel/project/auction/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-372dab03.js:45620:16)
at async CAC.\<anonymous\> (file:///home/samuel/project/auction/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:756:9)

I tried restarting my virtual machine. I've tried asking in Chat GPT and searching on Stack Overflow, but I can't find a solution to my problem.
By the way I have installed dfx.
